# Triggering multiple divs with transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm sure its me being daft on this topic.. but is there a way to trigger 2 or more divs with one transition?  For instance.. I have 2 box's.. when I click one box I want the width and height of both box's to change to 400px.  I would like to keep this in HTML and CSS if at all possible.. if not.. is there any other options?  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style>

    .box1{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:red;
    }

    .box2{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:black;
    }


</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Comment: have you tried anything? If yes can you please post some code?

Comment: Hey sorry.. here's some code.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

This is the CSS you need:

```
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.active {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  transition: height 1s linear, width 1s linear;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mYJVn/2/

Clicking one of the boxes increases the size of both.

If you don't want to use any JS at all, you will have to rely on the abuse of the "checkbox hack".

HTML:

```
<label for="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<div class="box"></div> 
<div class="box"></div>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:  all 1s linear;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
label {
    display: block;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mYJVn/4/

Comment: nice!  I should have mentioned I would prefer to keep this in html and CSS if that's possible.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a nonJS solution. This is really an abuse of the CSS though, but it works without javascript.